# How can I download Windows Server 2022 Standard ISO not Evaluation?

Tags: download, windows-server, windows-server-2022

I download Windows Server 2022 Standard from Microsoft but it's Windows Server 2022 Standard Evaluation edition: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/download-windows-server-2022

When I enter the serial number to Windows Server 2022 Standard Evaluation, it has error 0x80070032: https://imgur.com/OIhsTqu

I think it has error because this is the Windows Server 2022 Evaluation edition.

How can I [download Windows Server 2022 Standard ISO not Evaluation](https://getproductkey.net/download-windows-server-2022-standard-iso-free/)?

Comment: Enter the serial number and you will have nonevaluated version.

Comment: Where exactly did you download it from?

Comment: @YisroelTech - Probably from the evaluation website that Microsoft has.

Comment: @ttaihp - You would download the ISO from the Volume Licensing Service Center which of course requires a license key to the version your attempting to use.

Comment: Hi everybody. I download Windows Server 2022 Evaluation from Microsoft here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/download-windows-server-2022

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to spam. The accepted answer is by an account with a very similar name, and the links in it are suspicious.

Comment: @Romeo Ninov: When I enter the serial number to Windows Server 2022 Standard Evaluation, it has error 0x80070032: https://imgur.com/OIhsTqu

Comment: @Yisroel Tech: But if I convert Windows Server 2022 Standard Evaluation to Windows Server 2022 Standard, I can use the key: https://imgur.com/a/h8YdnMP

Comment: @Destroy666: Do you think my question is stupid?

Comment: No, I wrote "system", otherwise I'd select "spam" or "very suspicious" kind of a reason, but there's nothing like that.

Comment: @Destroy666: Ok thank you. I don't know why my question -4 vote :(

Comment: Because: 1) you posted from 2 new  accounts, 2) the answer had a link to random hosting site and now includes a video hosted on a random account (you should usually just embed screens here), 3) there's also still a link to suspiciously sounding getproductkey website, 4) the question wasn't asked in a way that would be as clear as possible. Looking at you still replying now it may have been a genuine attempt, but it went all wrong.

Comment: @Destroy666 - of course there's a spam flag, right under the question. If you found this in review, then you should have chased it through, not just finished the review with whatever limited options it presented. It's already been flagged to the mods for sick puppetry, but there's a strike on:\

Comment: @Tetsujin I flagged that so this is a very pointless message.

Comment: @Destroy666 - you're making little sense. I have no idea now what you're complaining about. First you say the system is stupid because you can't flag, then you question why I'm questioning your inability to flag… Could you please get all your ducks in a row, thank you. [& I just spotted my typo - s**o**ck puppetry, meh.]

Comment: Yes, you can't flag from **that queue**. That doesn't mean in any way that I didn't flag from a different place. You continue to fail to see this system is outright bad, inconsistent and not suitable for today's standards of the website. And you come to nonsense conclusions not related to my messages and the points I'm making in them in any way.

Comment: Now think - is it better to close it with a reason that basically forces people to read comments including mentions of scams, which will also get it autodeleted faster, or to just click "skip" as if nothing happened and hope that maybe perhaps enough people flag it as spam?

Comment: @Destroy666 - So why are you complaining in comments under a question rather than raising it properly on Meta? You are just adding noise to an already contentious issue. Can you not see that? Please **think** before posting. I've already raised a question about the abysmal level of review right now, and an answer on another related issue.

Comment: Because it's the only selectable close reason that made any sense in the queue? I can of course create a meta post too, I'll create it when I'll be read with material for it, though, not when I'm trying to close & report a question.

Comment: @Destroy666 - that it's the only selectable reason is of no import. If you were reviewing properly & not just dashing through them, you'd have opened the full question & flagged from there. It's up to **you** to review conscientiously. Anyway, this is not the place to discuss it. Raise  Meta if you have a point to make.

Comment: You're really not reading anything people write, as I wrote that I also flagged this not only once, but like 3 times at this point. Start by doing that if there should be any progressing discussion, then perhaps also do some reviews yourself, as I've never seen your input in some queues.

Comment: @Destroy666 - I'm going to stop responding to you. Rather than actually take a lesson onboard you'd rather flip the tables & make counter-accusations. You'll learn nothing at all that way.  Read https://meta.superuser.com/q/15043/347380 and https://meta.superuser.com/a/15048/347380 again & see if you can find something new in them, rather than just argue.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Microsoft says you can use retail key to convert Windows Server Evaluation to Standard/Datacenter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/upgrade-conversion-options#converting-an-evaluation-version-to-a-retail-version. I find people can use Windows Server 2022 Standard KMS key to convert Windows Server Evaluation to Standard edition. So I post it. People can use Windows Server 2022 Standard before they decide to buy key to activate it. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @music2myear: Do you have time? Can you create new virtual Windows Server 2022 Evaluation to test that you can use Windows Server 2022 KMS key to upgrade Windows Server 2022 Evaluation to Standard/Datacenter version. I don't know why Tetsujin report the answer. I say he create video to prove the answer is wrong but he can't give it. Mod deleted the answer but the answer is right. Or can you guide me how I send complain to Mod/Admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this question gets so much flak. Yes, it's a noob question, but it's legit.

From experience, GUI-based activation of the Eval edition often fails. You can still convert to the full version via the command line. Open the command prompt as an administrator, then issue the following command:

```
dism /Online /Set-Edition:ServerStandard /ProductKey:<your-key-here> /AcceptEula
```

Reboot when prompted. You may need to enter your key once again after the reboot, but this time the GUI dialog will accept it.

Edit: you *may* need to use GVLK in the command above. Grab the one according to your desired target edition and version from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kms-client-activation-keys
After the reboot, use your purchased key to activate.

Comment: The flak was for being a virtual duplicate of another question & answers [now all deleted as spam], posted by a set of sock puppets, linking to a pirate site.